# Laravel FCM Channel Driver not working when queued

Tags: laravel, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have implemented [FCM notification channel](https://github.com/laravel-notification-channels/fcm) on my laravel app.

The notifications have to be sent via mail and broadcast and because I'm using the mail channel, I have added the ShouldQueue contract in my notification class, but the FCM broadcast then stopped working.

If I remove the ShouldQueue implementation the notification is sent without problems.

I don't know what could it be or how to get this working without creating a specific notification for broadcast and without disabling queuing.

Any advice would help.

I've posted this [as an issue in the fcm github](https://github.com/laravel-notification-channels/fcm/issues/67) but they haven't answered so I'm turning to stackoverflow.

Comment: hi @CodeChuck were you able to solve this?

Comment: @dev21 sadly I had to disable queuing in my notifications, that;s the only way it worked